# How can i get the username id in th databas?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know why the username_id  didn't registred in the database , when I use : username = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) I have (username_id= NULL)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAW6A.png) but when I modified it by :  username = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) I have this message  : "IntegrityError at /Patformpage (1048, "Column 'username_id' cannot be null"),How can I resolve this problem , I need your help please.

Thank you in advance.

This is the code of forms.py

```
class PatForm(forms.Form):
    nom= forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'First_name'}))
    prénom = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Last_name'}))
    cin = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'CIN'}))
    sexe = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices= sexe))
    date_de_naissance = forms.DateField(widget=NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    quartier = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices= quartiers))
```

This is the code of  models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nom = models.CharField("Nom ",max_length=30)
    prénom = models.CharField("Prénom ", max_length=30)
    cin = models.CharField("C.I.N ", max_length=10)
    date_de_naissance = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    sexe = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=sex_types, default='1')
    quartier = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=quartier_types, default='0')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.prénom + ' ' + self.nom
```

This is the code of views.py

```
def Patformpage(request):
    form = PatForm(request.POST)
    context = {
        "form": PatForm
    }
    if request.method == 'GET':
     return render(request, 'base_app/inscription-finale-patient.html', context)


    elif form.is_valid() :

          newform= Patient(nom=form.cleaned_data['nom'],
                         prénom=form.cleaned_data['prénom'],
                         cin=form.cleaned_data['cin'],
                         date_de_naissance=form.cleaned_data['date_de_naissance'],
                         sexe=form.cleaned_data['sexe'],
                         quartier=form.cleaned_data['quartier'])

          newform.save()



    return redirect('accueil')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Patient` model needs to be passed an object of the `User` model. This means you need a valid `User` to give as the `username` field.

Comment: Allow me at the outset to thank you for your reply, So please how can I do it ??